# Line between connectors of the same node

Tags: graphviz

How can I do the drawing of arrow

```
A1:Port1 ->   A1:Port2 [dir=both]
```

nicer

So at least same connection point at the same point as the other connector. See picture.

[Line between connectors of the same node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wC7dX.jpg)

[Round line between connecoors of the same node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrLUJ.jpg)

```
digraph G {
    graph [rankdir = LR];

    node[shape=record];

    A1[label="{A1|{<Port1>Port 1|<Port2>Port 2 }}"];
    A2[label="{{<Port1>Port 1|<Port2>Port 2 }|A2}"];

   A1:Port1 ->   A1:Port2 [dir=both] 
   A1:Port1 -> A2:Port1 [dir=both] 


}
```

Comment: Try `A1:Port1:e ->   A1:Port2:e [dir=both]`. Is that better? Added the `:e` for "attaching" the edge.

Answer (score 0):

I would introduce an intermediate node:

```
digraph G {
    graph [rankdir = LR];

    node[shape=record];

    A1[label="{A1|{<Port1>Port 1|<Port2>Port 2 }}"];
    A2[label="{{<Port1>Port 1|<Port2>Port 2 }|A2}"];

   C[shape=point];
   A1:Port1 -> C;
   C -> A1:Port2;
   C -> A2:Port1;
}
```

so you get:

[image]

Comment: I thing that is a no go for dot and graphiz if it is not in an other way to handle. And if there are much more blocks, how to tell in which place the  C should be?

Comment: How should Graphviz fugure out where to split an edge if it is not told to do so? Intermediate nodes or connectors will be unavaidable if you want to achieve what you describe.

Comment: And is there a possibility to make virtuel rows like  { rank = same; C} {rank = same; A1}{rank = same; A2} rankorder = A1 C A2 ?

Comment: The blue arrow in your picture looks like splitting, and that's what also  @CapelliC has understood . Edges that stay within the node don't work. To your other question: Not exactly an answer but you may want to look at `subgraph`.

Comment: "How should Graphviz fugure out where to split an edge if it is not told to do so?" I do not want to split. The connection should go like an circle
   A1:Port1 -> A1:Port2 without drawing lines IN the block and with connecting at the same position like the other line 
   A1:Port1 -> A2:Port1 [dir=both] . Then everything would be good. So the main fault seen on my picture is, that graphviz connect somewere but not at the connectors right in the middle of the name.

Comment: I have added a new picture at the question, how I need the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Posting it as an answer, so that the resulting graph is clear:

```
digraph G 
{
    graph[ rankdir = LR, splines=line] ;
    node[ shape=record ];

    A1[ label= "{A1|{<Port1>Port 1|<Port2>Port 2 }}" ];
    A2[ label= "{{<Port1>Port 1|<Port2>Port 2 }|A2}" ];

    A1:Port1:e ->   A1:Port2:e [ dir=both ]
    A1:Port1   ->   A2:Port1   [ dir=both, minlen = 2 ]
}
```

producing

[image]